# Why does a merry-go-round with a child on it have no outside torque?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, torque

Suppose a child stands on a merry-go-round and rotates with it at the same speed, with coordinates centered at the center of the merry-go-round.

The center of a merry-go-round is a pole going into the ground.

Take our closed system to be the child and merry-go-round (which includes the pole). Notice this system has outside forces acting on it, indeed while I can't tell you which force is acting how much where, the momentum is non-constant (it always favors direction of velocity of the child). Thus we can calculate the total force applied to center of the mass.

However, how do we know (non-experimentally) that this force gives no torque to the system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The child and the merry go round are not an isolated system because the merry go round rotates about a pivot fixed into the ground.

The merry go round exerts a centripetal force on the child to keep them moving in a circle (this may be by friction or because the child is holding onto the merry go round). The child exerts an equal and opposite force on the merry go round. But the momentum of the merry go round does not change because the earth exerts an equal and opposite force to the child's force through the pivot. So there is an external force acting on the merry go round/child system. However, this pivot force acts through the system's centre of mass, so there is no external torque on the merry go round/child system.

Comment: I don't understand- say the pole has nontrivial radius, now the force applies to points not on the center, how do you explain that this force has no torque (my guess is that the force is radial and directed at one specific point, but i dont know how to justify it)

Comment: The force from the pole will be non-centered only if you consider friction.

Answer (score 0):

You need a torque as force in tangential direction  to compensate for the friction,  (without friction  it would go around after it was pushed in motion once) The centripetal force the pol has to exert is greater in the direction of the only child, so the pole has to sustain it,